# Can't start redmine server after restarting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have an installation of Redmine and RoR running on my Mac server.

Today I had to restart the server, and now my usual command to start the server,

```
ruby script/rails server webrick -e productionrail -v
```

returns this:

> rails: version unknown

Why?

Comment: I don't really know it :) but i thing no

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install rails --include-dependencies
```